# How can I preserve the right border of a fixed column in HTML tables while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, html-table

sandbox: https://codepen.io/test41564/pen/mdzaRrV

```css
.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

td:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 2
}

th:first-child,
th:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>01-11</th>
        <th>02-11</th>
        <th>03-11</th>
        <th>04-11</th>
        <th>05-11</th>
        <th>06-11</th>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Michel</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've tried a few tricks such as trying to set:

```css
td:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(2) { 
  position: sticky;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

But this doesn't get preserved while scrolling. I've tried to use pseudo elements like `::before` which I think is the key to do this but I'm unable to figure this out. I've even asked AI for help but nope, so now I'm trying stackoverflow if anyone else here knows whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `border-collapse: collapse;`.

`th` & `td` share borders with their siblings.

Try `border-collapse: separate;`.

```css
.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

td:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 2
}

th:first-child,
th:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>01-11</th>
        <th>02-11</th>
        <th>03-11</th>
        <th>04-11</th>
        <th>05-11</th>
        <th>06-11</th>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Michel</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```